# The order of elements in the HashMap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(5,a);
map.put(4,b);
map.put(3,c);
map.put(2,d);
map.put(1,e);
System.out.println(map);
```

Why the result is equal {1=e, 2=d, 3=c, 4=b, 5=a}?

Comment: Its not equal it is mapped, key = value

Comment: if you need a stort order in your map, you need a [SortMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Comment: try to run it multiple times and see the result

Answer (score 3):

Java [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't keep any order. API says

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Comment: "So, try some times, you will get different order of printing the content." It's also not guaranteed that it will be different. Are you sure that bogus orderings aren't returned deterministically?

Comment: @hexafraction : Not sure, I guess it, removed those lines

Answer (score 0):

From [`HashMap`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

A [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) would suffice for ordering by insertion order, and a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) may be used when order through a key's comparator is needed.